# How to change the receiver type(root node) after rebalancing a tree

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a binary tree in Go, but at the moment I'm stuck at the rebalancing of the tree. After rebalancing the root node will most likely be changed. Since the root node is the receiver type I have to change the value where the receiver type points to. The previous root node is used as another node now, which leads to the situation that this node is now also the root node.

```
func (n *treeNode) rebalance()  {  

    sorted := n.traverseTree([]*treeNode{})  //returns a sorted array of *treeNode
    newRoot := innerRebalance(sorted) //the method gives the correct result
    *n = *newRoot//now I have a cyclic reference in the tree

}
```

The rebalance is called within the add function. I do not want to make the rebalance method public since it is an implementation detail. I want to call the rebalance method within the Add method.

Interface:

```
type Store interface {
    Add(key string, value string)
    Get(key string) string
    Remove(key string) bool
}
```

treeNode struct:

```
type treeNode struct {
    bigger           *treeNode
    smaller          *treeNode
    key              string
    value            string
}
```

Example

Before rebalance

100(root) --> 150 --> 200

After rebalance

100 <-- 150(root) --> 200

After the assignment to *n

... 150 <-- 150 <-- 150 --> 200

How can I change the receiver type w/o getting a cyclic reference to itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to change is actually `**n`, so it can points to another node. You can not do that within the current scope. However, you can wrap the node and set the node outside of the method, and let the node's method returns a root.

For example,

```
type tree struct {
    root *treeNode
}

func (t *tree) Remove(key string) bool {
    root,ok := t.root.Remove()
    t.root = root
    return ok
}
```

And change `*treeNode.Add` to `func (*treeNode) Add(string) *treeNode`.